# RealityKit: Render an object under a grounding shadow

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

I have a placement marker (a simple plane with green corners) to visualize detected planes (via `ARRaycastResult`) in an `ARView`. This placement marker uses `UnlitMaterial` with a texture. Everything works fine as long as there is no other object added.

When I add another object, RealityKit also adds grounding shadow (invisible plane) right under the object. It works as a shadow plane and occludes everything behind it - including my placement marker.

Here is a picture of the placement marker (part of which is hidden under the shadow plane):

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this clipping? I was lookig for something like rendering order (as ARKit does have one), but have not fond anything in RealityKit yet.

I would like to keep the shadow plane if possible.

**Edit**: Added official name of the invisible plane (grounding shadow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reality kit automatically adds "grounding shadows" if the AnchoringComponent.Target is of type "plane". According to an Apple Engineer this can be aso simulated using a DirectionalLight with a Shadow and placing a plane (with an OcclusionMaterial) under the model. So the grounding shadow is probably also made out of OcclusionMaterial. This also explains why this grounding shadow occludes other objects.

There is an option to disable rendering of these grounding shadows. It can be done by inserting of `disableGroundingShadows` option into ARView's `renderOptions` property.

```
arView.renderOptions.insert(.disableGroundingShadows)
```

I have not yet found a way to override OcclusionMaterial (if any).